# cpan install RPC::XML error for Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl

When I try to install the RPC::XML module for Strawberry Perl v 5.20.2 for Windows 64 bit, I get the following errors....Can anyone shed light as to what the issue may be? I have already installed the XML::RPC module. (This worked fine for Strawberry Perl v 5.12)

```
C:\Users\administrator.JGORDON>cpan install RPC::XML
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.204)
Database was generated on Thu, 18 Jun 2015 16:48:26 GMT

Running install for module 'RPC::XML'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.95)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.068)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\R\RJ\RJRAY\RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.04)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.59)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4414)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.143240)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150220)
Configuring R/RJ/RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for RPC::XML
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RJ/RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----         RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz        ----
    DateTime::Format::ISO8601 [requires,optional]
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=lib\Apache\RPC\status
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\identity
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\introspection
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\listMethods
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\methodHelp
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\methodSignature

"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\multicall
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" etc\make_method --base=methods\status
cp lib/RPC/XML/Server.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Server.pm
cp methods\multicall.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\multicall.xpl
cp methods\status.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\status.xpl
cp lib/Apache/RPC/status.xpl blib\lib/Apache/RPC/status.xpl
cp methods\methodSignature.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\methodSignature.xpl
cp methods\methodHelp.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\methodHelp.xpl
cp lib/RPC/XML/Procedure.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Procedure.pm
cp lib/RPC/XML.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML.pm
cp lib/RPC/XML/Parser.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Parser.pm
cp methods\identity.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\identity.xpl
cp lib/RPC/XML/ParserFactory.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/ParserFactory.pm
cp lib/Apache/RPC/Status.pm blib\lib/Apache/RPC/Status.pm
cp lib/RPC/XML/Client.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Client.pm
cp lib/RPC/XML/Parser/XMLLibXML.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Parser/XMLLibXML.pm
cp lib/Apache/RPC/Server.pm blib\lib/Apache/RPC/Server.pm
cp methods\introspection.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\introspection.xpl
cp lib/RPC/XML/Parser/XMLParser.pm blib\lib/RPC/XML/Parser/XMLParser.pm
cp methods\listMethods.xpl blib\lib\RPC\XML\listMethods.xpl
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e cp -- etc\make_method b
lib\script\make_method
pl2bat.bat blib\script\make_method
  RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-
e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/
*.t
t/00_load.t ..................... ok
t/10_data.t ..................... ok
t/11_base64_fh.t ................ ok
t/12_nil.t ...................... ok
t/13_no_deep_recursion.t ........ ok
t/14_datetime_iso8601.t ......... skipped: DateTime::Format::ISO8601 not availab
le
t/15_serialize.t ................ ok
t/20_xml_parser.t ............... ok
t/21_xml_libxml.t ............... ok
t/25_parser_negative.t .......... ok
t/29_parserfactory.t ............ ok
t/30_procedure.t ................ ok
t/35_namespaces.t ............... ok
t/40_server.t ................... 1/91
t/40_server.t ................... 30/91 #   Failed test 'First live req: Check t
hat $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server.t line 245.

#   Failed test ''First live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 248.
#     'First live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server.t ................... 35/91
t/40_server.t ................... 36/91 #   Failed test 'Second live req: Check
that $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server.t line 293.

#   Failed test ''Second live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 295.
#     'Second live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'

t/40_server.t ................... 41/91 #   Failed test 'Third live req: Check t
hat $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server.t line 323.

#   Failed test ''Third live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 325.
#     'Third live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'

t/40_server.t ................... 47/91 #   Failed test 'Fourth live req: Check
that $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server.t line 368.

#   Failed test ''Fourth live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 370.
#     'Fourth live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'

t/40_server.t ................... 52/91 #   Failed test 'RT29351 live req: $res
is not an error'
#   at t/40_server.t line 417.

#   Failed test ''RT29351 live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 419.
#     'RT29351 live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server.t ................... 57/91
t/40_server.t ................... 59/91 #   Failed test ''system.listMethods res
ponse' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server.t line 475.
#     'system.listMethods response' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server.t ................... 83/91
t/40_server.t ................... 84/91 #   Failed test 'Arg-count testing of pr
ocedure types'
#   at t/40_server.t line 1107.
#          got: 'parse-error,parse-error,parse-error'
#     expected: '0,1,0'
t/40_server.t ................... 89/91 # Looks like you planned 91 tests but ra
n 90.
# Looks like you failed 12 tests of 90 run.
t/40_server.t ................... Dubious, test returned 12 (wstat 3072, 0xc00)
Failed 13/91 subtests
        (less 43 skipped subtests: 35 okay)
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 1/62
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 14/62 #   Failed test 'First live req: Check t
hat $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 142.

#   Failed test ''First live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 145.
#     'First live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 19/62
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 20/62 #   Failed test 'Second live req: Check
that $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 190.

#   Failed test ''Second live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 192.
#     'Second live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'

t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 25/62 #   Failed test 'Third live req: Check t
hat $res is not an error'
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 220.

#   Failed test ''Third live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 222.
#     'Third live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'

t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 31/62 #   Failed test 'RT29351 live req: $res
is not an error'
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 269.

#   Failed test ''RT29351 live req: parsed $res' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 271.
#     'RT29351 live req: parsed $res' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 36/62
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 38/62 #   Failed test ''system.listMethods res
ponse' isa 'RPC::XML::response''
#   at t/40_server_xmllibxml.t line 323.
#     'system.listMethods response' isn't a 'RPC::XML::response'
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... 62/62 # Looks like you failed 9 tests of 62.
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t ......... Dubious, test returned 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
Failed 9/62 subtests
        (less 33 skipped subtests: 20 okay)
t/41_server_hang.t .............. ok
t/50_client.t ................... 11/33
t/50_client.t ................... 16/33 #   Failed test 'simple_request/system.i
dentity returns correct value'
#   at t/50_client.t line 102.
#          got: undef
#     expected: 'RPC::XML::Server/1.73'

#   Failed test 'simple_request/system.identity left $RPC::XML::ERROR empty'
#   at t/50_client.t line 104.

t/50_client.t ................... 18/33 #   Failed test ''system.identity respon
se' isa 'RPC::XML::string''
#   at t/50_client.t line 109.
#     'system.identity response' isn't a 'RPC::XML::string'

t/50_client.t ................... 20/33 #   Failed test ''simple_request/system.
bad response' isa 'HASH''
#   at t/50_client.t line 130.
#     'simple_request/system.bad response' isn't defined

t/50_client.t ................... 23/33 #   Failed test ''send_request/system.ba
d response' isa 'RPC::XML::fault''
#   at t/50_client.t line 153.
#     'send_request/system.bad response' isn't a 'RPC::XML::fault'

t/50_client.t ................... 25/33 #   Failed test 'fault_handler correctly
 set $flag'
#   at t/50_client.t line 187.

#   Failed test ''fault_handler returned value' isa 'RPC::XML::fault''
#   at t/50_client.t line 189.
#     'fault_handler returned value' isn't a 'RPC::XML::fault'
t/50_client.t ................... 28/33
t/50_client.t ................... 30/33 #   Failed test ''cmpImg return value' i
sa 'RPC::XML::boolean''
#   at t/50_client.t line 260.
#     'cmpImg return value' isn't a 'RPC::XML::boolean'

t/50_client.t ................... 32/33 #   Failed test ''cmpImg return value (c
ompression)' isa 'RPC::XML::boolean''
#   at t/50_client.t line 276.
#     'cmpImg return value (compression)' isn't a 'RPC::XML::boolean'
# Looks like you failed 9 tests of 33.
t/50_client.t ................... Dubious, test returned 9 (wstat 2304, 0x900)
Failed 9/33 subtests
        (less 7 skipped subtests: 17 okay)
t/51_client_with_host_header.t .. ok
t/60_net_server.t ............... skipped: Net::Server tests not reliable on Win
dows platform
t/70_compression_detect.t ....... ok
t/90_rt50013_parser_bugs.t ...... ok
t/90_rt54183_sigpipe.t .......... skipped: Skipping *NIX signals-based test on W
indows platform
t/90_rt54494_blessed_refs.t ..... ok
t/90_rt58065_allow_nil.t ........ ok
t/90_rt58323_push_parser.t ...... ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/40_server.t                 (Wstat: 3072 Tests: 90 Failed: 12)
  Failed tests:  31-32, 37-38, 42-43, 48-49, 53-54, 59, 84
  Non-zero exit status: 12
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 91 tests but ran 90.
t/40_server_xmllibxml.t       (Wstat: 2304 Tests: 62 Failed: 9)
  Failed tests:  15-16, 21-22, 26-27, 32-33, 38
  Non-zero exit status: 9
t/50_client.t                 (Wstat: 2304 Tests: 33 Failed: 9)
  Failed tests:  16-18, 20, 23, 25-26, 30, 32
  Non-zero exit status: 9
Files=25, Tests=953, 163 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr +  0.03 sys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 3/25 test programs. 30/953 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports RJRAY/RPC-XML-0.79.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'RPC::XML'.
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be failing when in testing connections to the server, there may be some firewall or security issues on your machine preventing this test from completing.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up emailing the person who maintains the RPC::XML module, and he came up with a probable cause (for those who are interested).

To paraphrase, there seems to be a 'fork' emulation issue on Windows Perl. The failing code is trying to start a child HTTP listener, but there ends up not being any process or protocol listening on the port.